# Heap exception when write file on my server

Tags: java, file, exception, heap-memory, java-io

I have some problem with file write on server. I have two approach to file upload, one with Spring Multipart file, and it doesn't have problem, and one with byte array and when the file is big it gives `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`(I can see that the occupied ram increase with this method). I use byte array because I pass this file between web service REST and I put the stream into an object with also the field name.
This is my code for file write:

```
@Override
    public void storeAcquisition(Response response, String toStorePath) throws Exception{
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        LinkedHashMap<String,String> result= (LinkedHashMap<String,String>)response.getResult();        
        Files.write(Paths.get(toStorePath + "/" + result.get("name")), DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(result.get("content")));
    }
```

This is the sender method

```
byte[] file = getFile(filePath);
        if (file!=null){
            FileTransfer fileTransfer= new FileTransfer(file, Paths.get(filePath).getFileName().toString());
            //TODO POST TO SERVER
            Response responseSend = new Response(true, true, fileTransfer, null);
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            Response responseStatus = restTemplate.postForObject(serverIp + "ATS/client/file/?toStorePath={toStorePath}", responseSend, Response.class, toStorePath);
            return responseStatus;
        }
```

and

```
    public byte[] getFile(String path) throws Exception{
    if (Files.exists(Paths.get(path)))
        return Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
    else 
        return null;
}
```

Is there a problem in my code or the only solution is to use a better server?
The problem seems to be on `restTemplate.postForObject` and if I put a breakpoint on `LinkedHashMap<String,String>` result it doesn't come called.

Comment: Can you show exactly where the exception is thrown. It looks to me this is probably in `getFile`. Note that `readAllBytes` can be exceptionally huge: the file can be several terabytes. You should try to avoid reading an entire file into memory.

Comment: The sendler method is in a jar file imported in Matlab. I can try to call it in eclipse to see if the problem is it

Comment: The problem is on server side, on Files.write. The file is lesser than 500MB

Comment: does the write-server by any chance has less memory?

Comment: now I have tried on my machine, so the client and the server is on my laptop